# Error while deploying changes to Oracle Xstore POS via Oracle Xenvironment

Tags: oracle, openssl, keytool

I generated artifacts using Xadmin and I want to download it immediately to xstore , using xenvironment. But changes are not reflecting on Xstore. there are no errors in xenvironment logs.

For example :-

I changed one label "item Lookup" to "Item Lookup New" .So xenvironment picks zip file from Xadmin , it processes it but label doesn't change at Xstore UI.

XStore logs says , its unable to connect to Xenvironment due to SSL issue.

**Exception :-**

1-ERROR          2016-06-21 17:14:29,670     Exception handling IPC [xstore] and [UPDATE_PASSWDS] :: dtv.pos.appmanagement.IpcMessage.sendMessages(IpcMessage.java:186) [xenvPasswordFileCreationScheduler_Worker-1]
dtv.ipc.IPCException: [SOAPException: faultCode=SOAP-ENV:Client; msg=Error SSL connecting to localhost:9096: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException; targetException=java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException]
    at dtv.ipc.client.Client.call(Client.java:107)
    at dtv.pos.appmanagement.IpcMessage.sendMessage(IpcMessage.java:165)
    at dtv.pos.appmanagement.IpcMessage.sendMessages(IpcMessage.java:183)
    at dtv.pos.appmanagement.IpcMessage.invoke(IpcMessage.java:41)

Comment: Are you talking [about Oracle Retail Xstore Point of Service](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E62106_01/xpos/index.html)? If so you might want to specify the version you're using, and provide more details.

Comment: Yes ..same. Its version 7.1. Editing question. but I am unable to create new tag to  my question like xadmin, xstore, xenv etc.

Answer (score 2):

Xadmin creates artifacts and puts them on file server. It will also generate a manifest file in Xadmin DB.

Xenvironment will make a call to Xcenter to get a list of currently pending updates (Xcenter looks up manifests in Xadmin DB), get files from file server and process them based on their type (comes from manifest).

Once files are downloaded (depends on "download_time" - immediately or during store close) they will be applied (depends on "apply_time" - immediately or during store close) using Dataloader (part of Xstore).

"Item Lookup" suggests that you tried to change a button label = menu configuration change. Xstore needs to be restarted when configuration changes so nobody cares to tell it that configuration changed.

So, I'd suggest you to check logs and make sure:

- Xenvironment successfully received manifest
- Xenvironment successfully downloaded artifact
- artifact ended up in the /xstore/lib folder
- your target config element (if any) is on config path
- Xstore has been restarted

Comment: Thanks for the answer. SSL connecting error appeared due to IPC servers were not up in both xstore and xenviornment. After doing some SSL setu changes they started and this error went away. Regarding reflection of config changes they didn't reflected even after restart.

Comment: - is artifact in /xstore/lib/patch ?

Comment: - if you open it (it is a zip file) what files are in it (and what path they are in)?
- if it is MenuConfig.xml or ActionConfig.xml - put these xml files in /xstore/cust_config/localconfig (create if needed), restart Xstore and see if it changes your menu.

It looks like either: files didn't get downloaded by Xenvironment to Xstore or your config path is not setup properly